# Footnotes for a right-to-left phrase within a left-to-right paragraph

Tags: positioning, footnotes, right-to-left

I have an English paragraph with a right-to-left Hebrew phrase in the middle of the paragraph with a footnote referring to a word within that Hebrew phrase.

Should the footnote be positioned at the beginning of the Hebrew word or at the end?

Comment: It's not clear this is really a TeX question, but surely the footnote should go in the same relative position as you read the text (i.e. at the end of the word reading from right to left.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, you'll definitely put the `\footnote{}` command after your right-to-left phrase - it doesn't make sense otherwise. But then, you still have (at least) three options:

1. Footnote command within the right-to-left group of your right-to-left phrase,
   immediately after the actual phrase.
2. Footnote command within a separate right-to-left group, immediately closing your 
   phrase' right-to-left group.
3. Footnote command in a left-to-right group, immediately closing your 
   phrase' right-to-left group.

Here are screenshots with the output of all three approaches. It seems to me that the 3rd option is what you would want, but I can't categorically declare it to be superior.

(The body of the page:) [image]

(The footnote area:) [image]

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\raggedleft
\selectlanguage{english}
\verb|\R{...\footnote{...}}| \\
This is an English paragraph with a Hebrew word: \R{מילה\footnote{זוהי הערת התחתית הראשונה. \L{This is the second sentence of the first footnote.}}}
and then more English text.

\bigskip

\verb|\R{...}\R{\footnote{...}}| \\
This is a second English paragraph with a Hebrew word: \R{מילה}\R{\footnote{זוהי הערת התחתית השניה. \L{This is the second sentence of the second footnote.}}}
and then more English text.

\bigskip

\verb|\R{...}{\footnote{\R{...}}| \\
This is a second English paragraph with a Hebrew word: \R{מילה}\footnote{\R{זוהי הערת התחתית השלישית.} This is the second sentence of the third footnote.}
and then more English text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems as if #1 would be best because it's referring to the Hebrew word, but the footnote itself should be left-to-right like #3. Opinions?

Comment: @cgnieder: Done. `\R` is a babel macro for left-to-right languages.

Comment: @JoshVoigts: Unless the footnote is somehow part of the "run" of Hebrew text - and usually, it shouldn't be - I would disagree that 1 is best.